# Passport with feathersjs and local strategy, but without sessions

Tags: session, cookies, passport.js, passport-local, feathersjs

I'm stuck.

Can Featherjs with Passport authenticate with the local strategy and not have sessions enabled?

When I do enable sessions the first request is not authorised, but the second one is because the cookie from the first request is used. I don't want cookies used.

I've setup my code like:

```
var hooks = require('feathers-hooks');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var feathers = require('feathers');
var feathersPassport = require('feathers-passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = feathers();
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    done(null, "userid here");
}));


//Use the id to serialize the user
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

// Deserialize the user retrieving it form the user service
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done(null, "userid here");
});


var myService = {
    find: function (params, callback) {
        if (params.user) {
           console.log('yeh');
        }
        else {
            callback('not authorized', null);
        }
    }
};

// A shared session store must be provided.
//TODO This MemoryStore is not recommended for production
var store = new session.MemoryStore();

// Initialize the application
app.configure(feathers.rest())
    .configure(hooks())
    .configure(feathersPassport({
        secret: 'feathers-rocks',
        store: store
    }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/should/be/protected', passport.authenticate('local', {session: true}), myService);

app.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

feathers-passport is actually deprecated. Feathers definitely supports authentication without sessions (that's actually all it officially supports right now). There is a new-ish module called feathers-authentication. You might want to look at http://docs.feathersjs.com/authentication/readme.html.